# Detecting unicorn and dinosaur compilers

Tags: c

Rumor is that the next version of C will disallow [sign magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) and [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) signed integer encoding. True or not, it seems efficient to not have to code and test for those rare encodings.

Yet if code might not handle such cases as non-[2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), it is prudent to *detect* and fail such compilations today.

Rather than just look for that one kind of dinosaur¹, below is C code that looks for various unicorns² and dinosaurs.  Certainly some tests are more useful than others.

Review goal:

- Please report any **dinosaur**¹ and **unicorns**² compilers found by this code.
- Review how well this code would successfully flag true [passé](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pass%C3%A9) compilers and not report new innovative ones (e.g. 128-bit `intmax_t`.)
- Suggest any additional or refined tests.
- Pre-C11 compilers that lack `static_assert` may readily need a better `#define static_assert ...` than this code.  Better alternatives are appreciated, but not a main goal of this post.

Note: I am not trying to rate strict adherence to [IEEE_754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) and the like.

> Future readers concerning spelling and grammar in this post:   Although they should get corrected in an *answer*, edits to the *question's code* are not site appropriate.

---

```
/*
 * unicorn.h
 * Various tests to detect old and strange compilers.
 *
 *  Created on: Mar 8, 2019
 *      Author: chux
 */

#ifndef UNICORN_H_
#define UNICORN_H_

#include <assert.h>
#ifndef static_assert
  #define static_assert( e, m ) typedef char _brevit_static_assert[!!(e)]
#endif

#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/*
 *  Insure 2's complement
 *  Could also check various int_leastN_t, int_fastN_t
 */
static_assert(SCHAR_MIN < -SCHAR_MAX && SHRT_MIN < -SHRT_MAX &&
    INT_MIN < -INT_MAX && LONG_MIN < -LONG_MAX &&
    LLONG_MIN < -LLONG_MAX && INTMAX_MIN < -INTMAX_MAX &&
    INTPTR_MIN < -INTPTR_MAX && PTRDIFF_MIN < -PTRDIFF_MAX
    , "Dinosuar: Non-2's complement.");

/*
 *  Insure the range of unsigned is 2x that of positive signed
 *  Only ever seen one once with the widest unsigned and signed type with same max
 */
static_assert(SCHAR_MAX == UCHAR_MAX/2 && SHRT_MAX == USHRT_MAX/2 &&
    INT_MAX == UINT_MAX/2 && LONG_MAX == ULONG_MAX/2 &&
    LLONG_MAX == ULLONG_MAX/2 && INTMAX_MAX == UINTMAX_MAX/2, 
        "Dinosuar: narrowed unsigned.");

/*
 *  Insure char is sub-range of int
 *  When char values exceed int, makes for tough code using fgetc()
 */
static_assert(CHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX, "Dinosuar: wide char");

/*
 *  Insure char is a power-2-octet
 *  I suspect many folks would prefer just CHAR_BIT == 8
 */
static_assert((CHAR_BIT & (CHAR_BIT - 1)) == 0, "Dinosaur: Uncommon byte width.");

/*
 *  Only binary FP
 */
static_assert(FLT_RADIX == 2, "Dinosuar: Non binary FP");

/*
 *  Some light checking for pass-able FP types
 *  Certainly this is not a full IEEE check
 *  Tolerate float as double
 */
static_assert(sizeof(float)*CHAR_BIT == 32 || sizeof(float)*CHAR_BIT == 64,
    "Dinosuar: Unusual float");
static_assert(sizeof(double)*CHAR_BIT == 64, "Dinosuar: Unusual double");

/*
 *  Heavier IEEE checking
 */
static_assert(DBL_MAX_10_EXP == 308 && DBL_MAX_EXP == 1024 &&
    DBL_MIN_10_EXP == -307 && DBL_MIN_EXP == -1021 &&
    DBL_DIG == 15 && DBL_DECIMAL_DIG == 17 && DBL_MANT_DIG == 53,
    "Dinosuar: Unusual double");

/*
 *  Insure uxxx_t range <= int
 *  Strange when unsigned helper types promote to int
 */
static_assert(INT_MAX < UINTPTR_MAX, "Unicorn: narrow uintptr_t");
static_assert(INT_MAX < SIZE_MAX, "Unicorn: narrow size_tt");

/*
 *  Insure xxx_t range >= int
 *  Also expect signed helper types at least int range
 */
static_assert(INT_MAX <= PTRDIFF_MAX, "Unicorn: narrow ptrdiff_t");
static_assert(INT_MAX <= INTPTR_MAX, "Unicorn: narrow intptr_");

/*
 *  Insure all integers are within `float` finite range
 */
// Works OK when uintmax_t lacks padding
static_assert(FLT_RADIX == 2 && sizeof(uintmax_t)*CHAR_BIT < FLT_MAX_EXP,
    "Unicorn: wide integer range");
// Better method
#define UNICODE_BW1(x) ((x) > 0x1u ? 2 : 1)
#define UNICODE_BW2(x) ((x) > 0x3u ? UNICODE_BW1((x)/0x4)+2 : UNICODE_BW1(x))
#define UNICODE_BW3(x) ((x) > 0xFu ? UNICODE_BW2((x)/0x10)+4 : UNICODE_BW2(x))
#define UNICODE_BW4(x) ((x) > 0xFFu ? UNICODE_BW3((x)/0x100)+8 : UNICODE_BW3(x))
#define UNICODE_BW5(x) ((x) > 0xFFFFu ? UNICODE_BW4((x)/0x10000)+16 : UNICODE_BW4(x))
#define UNICODE_BW6(x) ((x) > 0xFFFFFFFFu ? \
    UNICODE_BW5((x)/0x100000000)+32 : UNICODE_BW5(x))
#define UNICODE_BW(x) ((x) > 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFu ? \
    UNICODE_BW6((x)/0x100000000/0x100000000)+64 : UNICODE_BW6(x))
static_assert(FLT_RADIX == 2 && UNICODE_BW(UINTMAX_MAX) < FLT_MAX_EXP,
    "Unicorn: wide integer range");

/*
 *  Insure size_t range > int
 *  Strange code when a `size_t` object promotes to an `int`.
 */
static_assert(INT_MAX < SIZE_MAX, "Unicorn: narrow size_t");

/*
 *  Recommended practice 7.19 4
 */
static_assert(PTRDIFF_MAX <= LONG_MAX, "Unicorn: ptrdiff_t wider than long");
static_assert(SIZE_MAX <= ULONG_MAX, "Unicorn: size_t wider thna unsigned long");

/*
 *  Insure range of integers within float
 */
static_assert(FLT_RADIX == 2 && sizeof(uintmax_t)*CHAR_BIT < FLT_MAX_EXP,
    "Unicorn: wide integer range");

// Addition code could #undef the various UNICODE_BWn

#endif /* UNICORN_H_ */
```

Test driver

```
#include "unicorn.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

---

¹ C is very flexible, yet some features applied to compilers simply no longer in use for over 10 years.  For compilers that used out-of-favor features (non-2's complement, non-power-of-2 bit width "bytes", non-binary floating-point, etc.) I'll call **dinosaurs**.

² C is very flexible for new platform/compilers too.  Some of these potential and theoretical compliers could employ *very* unusual features. I'll call these compilers **unicorns**.  Should one appear, I rather have code fail to compile than compile with errant functioning code.

Comment: Silly me - did not use an ASCII test yet....

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to ensure that `unsigned char` is a sub-range of `int` instead? To wit, `EOF` being distinct is useful.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, for `fgetc()` , `UCHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX` is better and `CHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX` insufficient.  Suggest forming an answer with that.

Comment: Serious question - how frequently do you run into these types of compilers? I think this is a cool idea! But honestly, I would never need it, as even doing cross-platform stuff, we usually know ahead-of-time which compilers we'll use, and none would have features this obscure. I'm always curious to learn a little about the things I don't run into myself.

Comment: @user1118321 "know ahead-of-time which compilers we'll use, and none would have features this obscure" --> that is what this file is for: to help make that assessment. Consider it a like a spell checker.  I certainly do not come across unicorns even sporadically, yet an automated review could help.  Additional tests could help detect near-unicorns.

Comment: I think it would be interesting to write a program that counts dinosaurs and unicorns in run-time. Giving a Dinosaur-Unicorn Score to compilers :) Kind of a test for compiler compliance, like paranoia.c is a test for float number compliance.

Comment: Typo: “insure” -> “ensure”.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Let me _assure_ you that there are many views such as [When to Use Insure, Ensure, and Assure](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/style-and-usage/when-to-use-insure-ensure-and-assure.html).   [You Say 'Tomato', I say 'Tomato'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7a4z7zLKts) ;-)

Comment: Tomeito/tomahto is about pronunciation, not spelling. Regarding ensure/insure, [“ There are some newspapers and magazines [...] that still use “insure” in both instances, but it’s fairly archaic to do so. Most publications differentiate the two.”](https://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/ensure-vs-insure). In any case, most people associate “insure” with buying insurance.

Comment: Since it is a most people issue, it is not a typo then.  "Tomeito/tomahto is about pronunciation" was to lighten the mode.

Comment: @chqrlie [Code must not be edited after an answer has been posted](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2376/52915)

Comment: @Mast: sorry about that, I should know :)... yet a corrected version of the code should be posted as an answer.

Comment: Are you also interested in looking for DeathStation 9000 intentionally-hostile compilers with maximally weird setups that nobody would ever want to use?  Your question phrasing is mostly about real-world practical compilers.  (IDK if there's anything a DS9k might do that isn't already covered.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica From OED: *There is considerable overlap between the meaning and use of insure and ensure. In both British and US English the primary meaning of insure is the commercial sense of providing financial compensation in the event of damage to property; ensure is not used at all in this sense. For the more general senses, ensure is the more usual word, but insure is also sometimes used, particularly in US English, e.g. bail is posted to insure that the defendant appears for trial; the system is run to ensure that a good quality of service is maintained.* It's ensure not insure.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Not that it's really important but since you tried going there I might as well go there too. Maybe US English uses it more though. I don't use US English so I don't really know. But it doesn't really matter I guess anyway. Stay safe in our crazy world!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- I think that `static_assert((CHAR_BIT & (CHAR_BIT - 1)) == 0` can be pretty safely replaced by `CHAR_BIT==8`. There are various old DSP compilers that would fail the test, but they are indeed dinosaur systems.
- stdint.h and constants like `SIZE_MAX`, `PTRDIFF_MAX` were added in C99. So by using such macros/constants, you'll essentially cause all C90 compilers to fail compilation.

  Are C90 compilers dinosaurs per your definition? If not, then maybe
  do some checks if `__STDC_VERSION__` is defined and if so what
  version. Because most of the exotic ones are likely to follow C90.

Comment: I was under the impression that some *modern* DSPs were word-addressable and had `CHAR_BIT` = 16, 24, or 32.  But I don't do embedded development so I might have read something old without realizing it.

Answer (score 10):

I'm appalled!  What kind of code are you writing that's so inflexible it needs all these tests?  ;-p

Seriously, it ought to be possible to enable only the tests that the including code needs, perhaps by predefining macros that declare its non-portabilities:

```
#ifdef REQUIRE_BINARY_FP
static_assert(FLT_RADIX == 2, "Dinosuar: Non binary FP");
#endif
```

(to pick a simple example)

---

On an extremely minor note, in the comments you've consistently written "insure" where you evidently mean "ensure".

---

Additional tests to consider:

- I've seen code that breaks if `'z' - 'a' != 25` and/or `'Z' - 'A' != 25`.
- Some code requires the existence of exact-width integer types such as `uint32_t`, which are not available on all platforms (it's possible this is covered by the power-of-two byte-width test, but I can't prove it).
- Perhaps some code requires `long double` to be bigger (in precision and/or range) than `double`?

Comment: A DeathStation9000 could choose not to provide `uint32_t` even if `CHAR_BIT=8`, even if `unsigned` would work as `uint32_t`.  That's unlikely for real-world C99 implementations, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes And technically *uintN_t* are optional. You can use e.g. *uint_least32_t* instead.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to fine answers [@Toby Speight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/215187/29485), [@Lundin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/215204/29485)  and [a related FP question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55300378/2410359), came up with additional idea/detail.

**Spelling***

"Dinosuar" --> "Dinosaur".

**[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) or not**

Could use a lengthy test of the *execution character set* `C11 §5.2.1 3`

```
A to Z
a to z
0 to 9
! " # % & ’ ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ { | } ~
space character, 
  and control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, and form feed.
some way of indicating the end of each line of text
```

Note that `$`, `@`, [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent), ASCII 127 and various control characters are not mentioned above.

```
  static_assert(
      'A' == 65 && 'B' == 66 && 'C' == 67 && 'D' == 68 && 'E' == 69 && 'F' == 70
          && 'G' == 71 && 'H' == 72 && 'I' == 73 && 'J' == 74 && 'K' == 75
          && 'L' == 76 && 'M' == 77 && 'N' == 78 && 'O' == 79 && 'P' == 80
          && 'Q' == 81 && 'R' == 82 && 'S' == 83 && 'T' == 84 && 'U' == 85
          && 'V' == 86 && 'W' == 87 && 'X' == 88 && 'Y' == 89 && 'Z' == 90,
      "Dinosaur: not ASCII A-Z");
  static_assert(
      'a' == 97 && 'b' == 98 && 'c' == 99 && 'd' == 100 && 'e' == 101
          && 'f' == 102 && 'g' == 103 && 'h' == 104 && 'i' == 105 && 'j' == 106
          && 'k' == 107 && 'l' == 108 && 'm' == 109 && 'n' == 110 && 'o' == 111
          && 'p' == 112 && 'q' == 113 && 'r' == 114 && 's' == 115 && 't' == 116
          && 'u' == 117 && 'v' == 118 && 'w' == 119 && 'x' == 120 && 'y' == 121
          && 'z' == 122, "Dinosaur: not ASCII a-z");
  static_assert('0' == 48, "Dinosaur: not ASCII 0-9");  // 1-9 follow 0 by spec.
  static_assert(
      '!' == 33 && '"' == 34 && '#' == 35 && '%' == 37 && '&' == 38
          && '\'' == 39 && '(' == 40 && ')' == 41 && '*' == 42 && '+' == 43
          && ',' == 44 && '-' == 45 && '.' == 46 && '/' == 47 && ':' == 58
          && ';' == 59 && '<' == 60 && '=' == 61 && '>' == 62 && '?' == 63
          && '[' == 91 && '\\' == 92 && ']' == 93 && '^' == 94 && '_' == 95
          && '{' == 123 && '|' == 124 && '}' == 125 && '~',
      "Dinosaur: not ASCII punct");
  static_assert(
      ' ' == 32 && '\t' == 9 && '\v' == 11 && '\f' == 12 && '\n' == 10,
      "Dinosaur: not ASCII space, ctrl");
   static_assert('\a' == 7 && '\b' == 8 && '\r' == 13,
      "Dinosaur: not ASCII spaces");
   // Not 100% confident safe to do the following test
   static_assert('$' == 36 && '@' == 64 && '`' == 96,
      "Dinosaur: not ASCII special");
```

---

[Edit 2019 Dec]

On review, incorporating [@Deduplicator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/215113/detecting-unicorn-and-dinosaur-compilers#comment415934_215113) idea: `CHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX` is not a strong enough test to avoid trouble with `fgetc()`, but should use `UCHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX`.  This makes certain that the number of possible characters returned from `fgetc()` is less than the positive `int` range - preventing a collision with `EOF`.

```
/*
 *  Insure char is sub-range of int
 *  When char values exceed int, makes for tough code using fgetc()
 */
// static_assert(CHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX, "Dinosaur: wide char");
static_assert(UCHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX, "Dinosaur: wide char");
```

Comment: I don't suppose there's any way to rewrite those ASCII range tests as `"ABCDEFGHI...XYZ" with a check for `str[i+65] == i`.  Probably not in a way compatible with static_assert, without C++ constexpr functions to allow a loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes I do not see a way.  Perhaps `static_assert('A' == 65 && 'B' == 'A' + 1 && 'C' == 'B' + 1 && 'D' == 'C' + 1 ...` for a more friendly/sane looking test?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```c
static_assert(SCHAR_MIN < -SCHAR_MAX && SHRT_MIN < -SHRT_MAX &&
    INT_MIN < -INT_MAX && LONG_MIN < -LONG_MAX &&
    LLONG_MIN < -LLONG_MAX && INTMAX_MIN < -INTMAX_MAX &&
    INTPTR_MIN < -INTPTR_MAX && PTRDIFF_MIN < -PTRDIFF_MAX
    , "Dinosuar: Non-2's complement.");
```

I prefer:

```c
static_assert(  SCHAR_MIN < -SCHAR_MAX,   "Dinosaur: Non-2's complement.");
static_assert(   SHRT_MIN < -SHRT_MAX,    "Dinosaur: Non-2's complement.");
static_assert(    INT_MIN < -INT_MAX,     "Dinosaur: Non-2's complement.");
static_assert(   LONG_MIN < -LONG_MAX,    "Dinosaur: Non-2's complement.");
static_assert(  LLONG_MIN < -LLONG_MAX,   "Dinosaur: Non-2's complement.");
static_assert( INTMAX_MIN < -INTMAX_MAX,  "Dinosaur: Non-2's complement.");
static_assert( INTPTR_MIN < -INTPTR_MAX,  "Dinosaur: Non-2's complement.");
static_assert(PTRDIFF_MIN < -PTRDIFF_MAX, "Dinosuar: Non-2's complement.");
```

Granted, this code won't survive any automated code formatting, but it's much easier to grasp than the all-in-one assertion. Also, when one of the assertions fails, you know exactly which of these types is unusual.

On another topic: `UNICODE_BW1` is a typo, it should be `UNICORN_BW1`.

Comment: This approach does have an advantage if needing to compile pre-C99 as it is cleaner to `#if define(LLONG_MIN)` around `static_assert(  LLONG_MIN < -LLONG_MAX,  ...` and any select integer types.