# Fixed-Size Floating-Point Types

Tags: c, floating-point

I have created my own personal data structure libraries for C and I've re-engineered it about two times now and I've added alot of preprocessor checks and defines concerning OS type and compiler type.

One thing I've wanted to add to my personal libraries is having an informal *"standard"* fixed-size floating-point types.

```
#ifndef __float32_t_defined
#   if defined(COMPILER_CLANG) || defined(COMPILER_GCC)
#       define __float32_t_defined
        typedef float float32_t TYPE_MODE(__SF__);
#   elif FLT_MANT_DIG==24
#       define __float32_t_defined
        typedef float float32_t;
#   elif DBL_MANT_DIG==24
#       define __float32_t_defined
        typedef double float32_t;
#   endif
#endif

#ifndef __float64_t_defined
#   if defined(COMPILER_CLANG) || defined(COMPILER_GCC)
#       define __float64_t_defined
        typedef float float64_t TYPE_MODE(__DF__);
#   elif FLT_MANT_DIG==53
#       define __float64_t_defined
        typedef float float64_t;
#   elif DBL_MANT_DIG==53
#       define __float64_t_defined
        typedef double float64_t;
#   elif LDBL_MANT_DIG==53
#       define __float64_t_defined
        typedef long double float64_t;
#   endif
#endif

#ifndef __floatmax_t_defined
#   if defined(COMPILER_CLANG) || defined(COMPILER_GCC)
#       define __floatmax_t_defined
        typedef double floatmax_t TYPE_MODE(__XF__);
#   elif LDBL_MANT_DIG>=64
#       define __floatmax_t_defined
        typedef long double floatmax_t;
#   elif DBL_MANT_DIG>=64
#       define __floatmax_t_defined
        typedef double floatmax_t;
#   else
#       define __floatmax_t_defined
        typedef float floatmax_t;
#   endif
#endif
```

For Clang and GCC, I use the compiler extension that checks machine mode and sets the type definition to the largest width of the floating point type. I added further type definition checks in the event Clang or GCC are not used.

my main question is that, given the macros in `float.h`, is checking float size by its mantissa a wise/safe thing to do? If not, what alternative can I take?

Comment: It the goal to have a 32-bit `float32_t`, a 64-bit `float64_t` regardless of their internal proprieties?

Comment: What is the goal of `floatmax_t`?

Comment: @chux No, the goal of `float32_t` and `float64_t` is that those types are always their fixed size. The goal of `floatmax_t` is to be the largest float width possible, which might either be the same as `float32_t`, or `float64_t`, or even higher than those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`float32_t`   `float64_t`**

Since the goal is:

> `float32_t` and `float64_t` is that those types are always their fixed size

the macros nearly achieve that.

---

> is checking float size by its mantissa a wise/safe thing to do? If not, what alternative can I take?

**Big caveat**: OP's expressed goal is *same size*, not same *encoding*.  Two systems may have a 32-bit `float`, yet different mantissa, exponent range and other properties.  The biggest "safety" concern is assuming same floating point properties with same *size*.

C allows for a great diversity of implementations though.  The macros accommodate most current compilers well, yet they are not specified to be always `typedef` 32/64 bit types.

To be clear, checking `xxx_MANT_DIG, FLT_RADIX, xxx_MIN_EXP, ...` is **not** sufficient, in general, even though it may be practically sufficient.

It fundamental comes down to:

> what should code do if it encounters a novel implementation?

I'd go with testing for the [usual suspects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtSmfws0_To) and expand code when I encounter a true counter case.

```
#ifndef __float64_t_defined
  #if FLT_RADIX==2 && DBL_MANT_DIG==53 && DBL_MIN_EXP == -1021
    #define __float64_t_defined
    typedef double float64_t;
  #elif FLT_RADIX==2 && FLT_MANT_DIG==53 && FLT_MIN_EXP == -1021
    #define __float64_t_defined
    typedef float float64_t;
  // Expand list for variants that I have found 
  #elif FLT_RADIX==2 && DBL_MANT_DIG==TBD && DBL_MIN_EXP == TBD
  #else
    #error TBD code for float64_t
  #endif
#endif
```

Note: Code like `DBL_MANT_DIG==24` is not even C compliant with `FLT_RADIX==2`.  `DBL_MANT_DIG >= 34` to meet precision requirements.   This looks like a test for a non-real machine.

---

I recommend 2 additions:

Report fail to `typedef` right away with `#error`

```
#   elif LDBL_MANT_DIG==53
#       define __float64_t_defined
        typedef long double float64_t;

// Add
#   else
#     error TBD code for float64_t

#   endif
```

With C11 or later, use `_Static_assert`

```
_Static_assert(sizeof (float64_t)*CHAR_BIT == 64, "Unexpected `float64_t` size");
```

With early compilers, see [Static assert in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3385694/2410359) and others.

---

**floatmax_t**

After taking advantage or known `COMPILER_CLANG, COMPILER_GCC` compilers, I'd recommend more conventional code - Simply test for [C99 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4991754/2410359).

```
#ifndef __floatmax_t_defined
#   if defined(COMPILER_CLANG) || defined(COMPILER_GCC)
#       define __floatmax_t_defined
        typedef double floatmax_t TYPE_MODE(__XF__);
#   elif (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L)
#       define __floatmax_t_defined
        typedef long double floatmax_t;
#   else
#       define __floatmax_t_defined
        typedef double floatmax_t;
#   endif
#endif
```

---

Similar question I posed

[Detecting unicorn and dinosaur compilers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/215113/29485)