# 4 different implementations of modulo with fully defined behavior

Tags: c, gcc

I've implemented the 3 variants of the modulo operation described on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Variants_of_the_definition).
The goal is to have fully defined behavior for all inputs.

## Code

### Implementation with truncated division (result has the same sign as the dividend)

```c
int32_t rem(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    if (y == 0) exit(-1);
    if (y == -1) return 0;
    return x % y;
}
```

This one is the simplest since it's already how the `%` operator is implemented in C.
We have to take care of two edge cases though:

- If `y == 0` it's an invalid operation; `exit(-1)`.
- `INT32_MIN % -1` is undefined behavior, so I've hard-coded the result for `y == -1`.

### Implementation with floored division (result has the same sign as the divisor)

```c
int32_t mod(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    if (y == 0) exit(-1);
    if (y == -1) return 0;
    return x - y * (x / y - (x % y && (x ^ y) < 0));
}
```

This one is a bit trickier.

We still have to handle the two previous edge cases.
However, the modulo is computed differently: `x - y * floor(x / y)`.
We can't use `floor` here because we're working with integers, so the formula looks like this:

`x - y * (x / y - {1 if x isn't a multiple of y and the result of x / y is negative, 0 else})`
`x - y * (x / y - {1 if x % y and the result of x / y is negative, 0 else})`
`x - y * (x / y - {1 if x % y and (x or y, but not both, is negative), 0 else})`
`x - y * (x / y - {1 if x % y and (x ^ y) < 0, 0 else})`
`x - y * (x / y - (x % y && (x ^ y) < 0))`

### Implementation with Euclidean division (result is always positive)

#### Portable implementation

```
int32_t euc1(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    if (y == 0) exit(-1);
    if (y == -1) return 0;
    if (y == INT32_MIN) return x >= 0 ? x : INT32_MAX + x + 1;
    y = abs(y);
    return x - y * (x / y - (x < 0 && x % y));
}
```

It's basically the same implementation as the previous one, except that we use the absolute value of `y`.
Also, `(x ^ y) < 0` was simplified to `x < 0` because `y` is always positive (we use the absolute value).
However `abs(INT32_MIN)` is undefined behavior (because `abs(INT32_MIN) = INT32_MAX + 1` which is not representable) so we have to take care of this special case:

- If `x >= 0`, we have `x % (INT32_MAX + 1) = x` because `x` is always inferior to `INT32_MAX + 1`.
- If `x < 0`, we have `x % (INT32_MAX + 1) = INT32_MAX + 1 + x`, then we reorder operations to avoid overflow on signed integers which is undefined behavior: `INT32_MAX + x + 1` (remember that `x` is negative).

#### GCC implementation

```
int32_t euc2(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    if (y == 0) exit(-1);
    if (y == -1) return 0;
    if (y != INT32_MIN) y = abs(y);
    int32_t tmp = x / y - (x < 0 && x % y);
    __builtin_mul_overflow(y, tmp, &tmp);
    __builtin_sub_overflow(x, tmp, &tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

This implementation is the same as the portable one, except for the handling of the `y = INT32_MIN` edge case: there is less conditional logic, making it potentially easier to optimize.

If `y == INT32_MIN` we don't compute the absolute value because it's undefined behavior, then we continue the execution as nothing happened. A multiplication and a subtraction were replaced by their [built-in functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html#Integer-Overflow-Builtins) counterparts to avoid undefined behavior on overflow.
Because of black magic it works:

- If `x >= 0` we have `x / INT32_MIN - (x < 0 && x % INT32_MIN) = 0`, then `INT32_MIN * 0 = 0`, then `x - 0 = x`, so the result is `x` as expected.
- If `INT32_MIN < x < 0` we have `x / INT32_MIN - (x < 0 && x % INT32_MIN) = -1`, then `INT32_MIN * -1 = INT32_MIN` (built-in function defined behavior), then `x - INT32_MIN = INT32_MAX + x + 1` (built-in function defined behavior), so the result is `INT32_MAX + x + 1` as expected.
- If `x == INT32_MIN` we have `INT32_MIN / INT32_MIN - (INT32_MIN < 0 && INT32_MIN % INT32_MIN) = 1`, then `INT32_MIN * 1 = INT32_MIN`, then `INT32_MIN - INT32_MIN = 0`, so the result is `0` as expected.

## Questions

Is there an error somewhere, something that i missed? Like a set of inputs that don't give the right result.

If this code really undefined behavior free?

Can it be simplified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an error somewhere, something that i missed? Is there an error somewhere, something that i missed?

Certainly have most of main street covered.

`if (y == -1) return 0;` is a nice trick.

`y = abs(y);` fails 32-bit math when `int` is 16-bit.  Could use `labs()` or conditional code or an `if()` block.  (Only real portability bug I see.)

Pedantic: `int32_t` is an optional type.  It is missing and code fails to compile on select ([dinosaur](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/215113/29485)) machines that do not have 32-bit unpadded 2's complement.

Pedantic: On a select (unicorn) machine where `int` is 64-bit and `int32_t` exist, promotions occur.  I do not *see* a problem though.

Pedantic: Usage of `x ^ y` obliges 2's complement encoding for correct functionality which is the case with `intN_t` here , but not *all* integers on *all* machines.

---

Adding a test harness would help.

---

> Can it be simplified?

A shot at simplifying [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) (result is always non-negative).  Similar code may apply to the other 2 cases.

```
// Substitute `int` for `int32_t`, `long long`, etc.
int modulo_Euclidean(int x, int y) {
  if (y == 0) exit(-1);
  if (y == -1) return 0;
  int m = x % y;
  if (m < 0) {
    m = (y < 0) ? m - y : m + y;
  }
  return m;
}
```

Does not require `intN_t` math<sup>*</sup>, 2's complement, no padding, range constants, nor extended math.

---

It would be interesting to see if 64-bit math was really slower or a reasonable candidate.

```
int32_t mod_rem_or_euc(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
  if (y == 0) exit(-1);
  int_fast64_t m = (int_fast64_t) x % y;
  ...
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> `intN_t` types are 2's complement, no padding.

Comment: Thanks for this review. I like your Euclidean modulo simplification because it gets rid of the `abs` function that can cause problem when fed with int32_t.

Answer (score 4):

The code *may* be free of undefined behavior, but it relies on *implementation-defined behavior* because of the `exit(-1)`. Read its definition in the C standard, not in POSIX or even Linux. Of these, the C standard gives the fewest guarantees.

Your code is definitely missing a test suite that demonstrates all the edge cases. Without such a test suite, it's not apparent how much thought you invested into this code.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an error somewhere, ... Like a set of inputs that don't give the right result.

Code lacks basic tests to answer that.

Sample test harness. (It lacks `% 0` tests.)

OP's `euc1()` tested successfully on a 32-bit `int` machine.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int32_t euc1(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
  if (y == 0) exit(-1);
  if (y == -1) return 0;
  if (y == INT32_MIN) return x >= 0 ? x : INT32_MAX + x + 1;
  y = abs(y);
  return x - y * (x / y - (x < 0 && x % y));
}

int32_t euc1_ref(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
  if (y == 0) return -1;
  int64_t m = (int64_t) x % y;
  if (m < 0) {
    if (y < 0) m -= y;
    else m += y;
  }
  assert(m >= 0);
  assert(m <= INT32_MAX);
  return (int32_t) m;
}

int test_euc(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
  int32_t m1 = euc1_ref(x, y);
  int32_t m2 = euc1(x, y);
  if (m1 != m2) {
    printf("(%ld, %ld) --> %ld, %ld\n", (long) x, (long) y, (long) m1, (long) m2);
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

// Could make this a little more efficient, but something to get things started.
int32_t rand_int32(void) {
  union {
    uint32_t u;
    int32_t i;
  } x;
  x.u = (unsigned) rand();
  x.u = (x.u << 15) ^ (unsigned) rand();
  x.u = (x.u << 15) ^ (unsigned) rand();
  return x.i;
}
    
int tests_euc(void) {
  int32_t t[] = { INT32_MIN, INT32_MIN + 1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, INT32_MAX - 1,
  INT32_MAX };
  size_t n = sizeof t / sizeof t[0];
  for (size_t yi = 0; yi < n; yi++) {
    int32_t y = t[yi];
    if (y == 0)
      continue;
    for (size_t xi = 0; xi < n; xi++) {
      int32_t x = t[xi];
      int retval = test_euc(x, y);
      if (retval) {
        return retval;
      }
    }
  }
  n = 1000u*1000*1000; // Number of random tests
  while (n) {
    int32_t y = rand_int32();
    if (y == 0) {
       continue;
    }
    int32_t x = rand_int32();
    int retval = test_euc(x, y);
    if (retval) {
      return retval;
    }
    n--;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  tests_euc();
  puts("Done");
}
```